# main thread consumer and other threads producer

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

My questions is, I have a data set of 1000 records. I want 3 threads that process the data like this,
thread1 from record 1 to 300, thread2 from 301 to 600 and so on. One thread can make a request and fetch 50 records at a time, create an object and put it in a queue.
Main thread will simultaneously read data from the queue.

Below is the code, the problem I am facing is that recordRead variable tells the starting point from where the thread should start reading the records. 
But how can I set different value for each thread e.g for thread1 it should be 0 and recordsToRead should be 300 and for thread2, recordRead should be 300 and recordsToRead to be 300+300=600 and for last thread it should be 600 and upto the end. 
pagesize=50
pagesize,recordRead and recordToRead are all variables that belong to main class and main thread.

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    while(nThreads > 0) {
        nThreads--;
        service.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                do {
                    int respCode = 0;
                    int RecordsToRead = div;
                    JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject();
                    jsObj.put("pagesize", pageSize);
                    jsObj.put("start", recordsRead);
                    jsObj.put("searchinternalid", searchInternalId);

                    try {
                        boolean status = req.invoke(jsObj); 
                        respCode = req.getResponseCode();

                    } catch (Exception e) {         
                        req.reset();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return true;
                    }
                    JSONObject jsResp = req.getResponseJson();
                    //here jsResp will be added to ArrayBlockingQueue.

                    req.reset();
                }while(!isError && !isMaxLimit && recordsRead < RecordsToRead);

            }

        });
    }
```

After this loop will be the code of main thread reading the queue.
how can I set recordsRead and recordToread for all threads.

And how to make main thread wait untill atleast one thread inserts an object in queue.

Comment: You can create subclass of `Runnable` with start position (and whatever else) as class ctor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I see in you definition two problems. First problem is to perform parallel chunk computation and second one is to create a continous pipeline from this. Lets start from the first problem. To make parallel computations with predefined size the best option fmpv will be to use fork-join framework. Not only by performance (work stealing is really effective) but also due to simpler code. But since you are limited to 3 threads for me it also seems valid to use threads directly. Simply what you want can me implemented by this way:

```
    final int chunkSize = 300;
    //you can also use total amount of job
    //int totalWork = 1000 and chunk size equals totalWork/threadsNumber
    final int threadsNumber = 3;

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadsNumber];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < threadsNumber; ii++) {
        final int i = ii;

        threads[ii] = new Thread(() -> {
           //count your variable according the volume
            // for example you can do so
            int chunkStart = i * chunkSize; 
            int chunkEnd = chunkStart + chunkSize;
            for(int j = chunkStart; j < chunkEnd; j++) {
              //object creation with necessary proprs
              //offer to queue here
            }
        });

        threads[ii].start();
    }

    //your code here
    //take here

    for (int ii = 0; ii < threadsNumber; ii++) {
        try {
         //this part is only as example
         //you do not need it                
         //here if you want you can also w8 for completion of all threads
            threads[ii].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now about the second problem with consuming. For this puprose you can use for example ConcurrentLinkedBlockingQueue  (http://www.jgroups.org/javadoc/org/jgroups/util/ConcurrentLinkedBlockingQueue.html). Make offer in producer threads and use take method in main.

But to be honest i still did not get the reason of your problem. Do you want to create continuous pipeline or it is just one-time computation?

Also i will recommend you to take this course: https://www.coursera.org/learn/parallel-programming-in-java/home/welcome.
This will help you exactly with your problem and provide various solutions. There are also concurrent and distributed computing courses.